# Compute the sum of absolute values with stl algorithms

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm, reduction

I would like to use the algorithms of `std::numeric` to compute the sum of the absolute values of an array, in order to use the gnu parallel extensions (array size is > 500000).

Here is my current code :

```
double ret = 0;
for (auto i = 0U; i < length; ++i)
{
    ret += std::abs(tab[i]);
}
return ret;
```

So I thought about doing :

```
auto sumabs = [] (double a, double b) 
{
    return std::abs(a) + std::abs(b);
} 

std::accumulate(tab, tab + length, 0, sumabs);
```

But it is inefficient because if a reduction algorithm is performed (which I sincerely hope for the sake of fast computation!), `std::abs` will be applied to values which are already >= 0.

So is there any way to do this ? perhaps performing the first step of the reduction "by hand", and let `std::accumulate` do a simple addition between the rest ? But there will be a copy and a memory hit...

Comment: Is `abs` even slow? Why don't you write a `constexpr` one if it bugs you? It's pretty easy to implement a naive one for your situation. By the way, in C++11 we have `std::begin(tab)`, `std::end(tab)`.

Comment: does `std::begin` and `std::end` work with it even if it is declared `double *tab` ? It would be ludicrous!

And I don't really understand... write a constexpr abs ? What would it do ?

Comment: @aaronman that's for ints, OP needs double. Double is even simpler - just clear the sign bit, no branching.

Comment: then whats the problem? for a double it's definitely 1 instruction no branching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the accumlate method and perform the "by hand" evaluation inside the function. By the way in your code you apply the abs method to the first parameter which is not necessary.

```
int fAccumulate (int accumulated, int accumulateIncrement) 
{
    int retValue = 0;
    if (accumulateIncrement >= 0)
    {
        retValue = accumulated + accumulateIncrement;
    }
    else
    {
        retValue = accumulated + std::abs(accumulateIncrement);
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

The use of this code could be:

```
int init = 0;
int numbers[] = {10,20,-30};
int a = std::accumulate (numbers, numbers+3, init, fAccumulate);
```

Comment: Mhh, ok, works for me! I'll try to do some benchmarks to see the inpact with the branch prediction.

Comment: This solution makes no sense you are still calling abs on it and you are branching which is never good

Comment: I am making the assumption that based on your use of the C++ Standard Library you require portability and wish to avoid compiler dependent code especially when dealing with non integral types like float and double.

Answer (score 1):

This will use the minimum number of calls to `std::abs` necessary:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    static const auto abssum = [] (auto x, auto y) {return x + std::abs(y);};
    
    float entries[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};

    auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(entries), std::end(entries), 0.0f, abssum);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `0.0f`, and avoid `entries[0]` entirely?

Comment: @DarkZeros Yes, that's clearer. I was overly trying to be clever at the time.